# HTML5 Unicode ID Attribute

Tags: html, unicode, attributes

Is it okay to set a HTML5 ID attribute to a string containing characters in non-latin languages?

Comment: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML 4.01 supports any character in class names, but only in HTML 5 you can that in IDs too.
For further reading see [Mathias Bynens's blog](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class).